# How to have multiple instances of filebeat load balance Netflow input?

Tags: load-balancing, elasticsearch, netflow, filebeat

I have a very high volume Netflow input stream, and I was hoping that I could run multiple instances of Filebeat and load-balance the Netflow traffic over the Filebeat instances, and then write to a single remote Elasticsearch.

I've read about load-balancing to multiple outputs, but I'm looking for load-balancing from multiple inputs.

I can split the Netflow input over 2 physical ports, but I'm not sure how I can configure 2 instances of Filebeat to each be tied to a specific physical port.

Comment: In general : two start-up scripts for filebeat that each load a different and unique configuration file that configures each instance to listen to different ports i.e. with different `var.netflow_host` 
and 
`var.netflow_port` settings. Or is your problem more complicated?

Comment: I thought `var.netflow_port` refers to the UDP port of the netflow (IPFIX in my case) packets? I currently have filebeat listen to Port 4739, which is the dest port of the IPFIX packets. All of the packets would be sending to Port 4739.

Is `var.netflow_host` the interface IP? If so, I might be able to configure the IPFIX packets to send to 2 different IP address, for each of the interfaces. I currently have it set to `0.0.0.0` as I only have one input.